# how to pass value of cells in HTML table to PHP variables

Tags: php, html

This is what I am trying to do. List of tables coming from database. Then user will be able to preview the details to pdf for them to print. However, I am quite struggling with this problem view screenshot: [image: view screenshot] How do I pass the value of the cells to variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing value from PHP to jquery you can do it with the use of html attributes just like `data-id`..you can do it like this.

```
<button class="print" data-id='<?php echo $the_value; ?>' value="Print"/>
```

Then you can access it in the jquery with this:

```
$(".print").on("click", function(){
    var my_value = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(my_value); //this is to echo the value; 
});
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted any code or markup it is hard to give a firm answer as the actual structure and tags of the html are unknown. However, perhaps you can make use of the following snippet of javascript

```
<table id='pdf'>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test office </td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Print' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>test name 1</td>
        <td>testicle</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Print' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>test name 2</td>
        <td>test icicle</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Print' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
    var bttns=document.getElementById('pdf').querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
    for( var b in bttns )if( bttns[ b ].nodeType==1 )bttns[ b ].onclick=function(){

        var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var col = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
        var data=[];
        for( var td in col )if( col[ td ].nodeType==1 )data.push( td.innerHTML );

        /* send the data via ajax ~ alert only for example */
        alert( data );

    }.bind( bttns[ b ] );
</script>
```